# using block.blockhash instead of block.timestamp for 30 minutes

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, timestamp

I would like to check if the time has passed 30 minutes before executing a function in my contract. I know how it is done using block.timstamp .. But I want to use block.clockhash as it is more secure... how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The usage of `block.timestamp` has good security properties and you might have misunderstood something. Unless you know what you are doing please stick to `block.timestamp`.

Comment: I am using a tool Securify to formally verify my code .. and it shows using block.timestamp as a security vulnerability.  I was hoping to improve my code

Comment: Any tools you know of that you may suggest?